# Can you explain this Java hash map key collision?

Tags: java, hashmap, collision

I have a HashMap and is used in the following way:

```
HashMap<SomeInterface, UniqueObject> m_map;

UniqueObject getUniqueObject(SomeInterface keyObject)
{
     if (m_map.containsKey(keyObject))
     {
         return m_map.get(keyObject);
     }
     else
     {
         return makeUniqueObjectFor(keyObject);
     }
}
```

My issue is that I'm seeing multiple objects of different classes matching the same key on m_map.containsKey(keyObject).

So here are my questions:

1. Is this possible? The Map interface says it uses equals() to compare if the key is not null. I haven't overridden equals() in any of my SomeInterface classes. Does this mean the equals method can be wrong?
2. If the above is true, how do I get HashMap to only return true on equals() if they are in fact the same object and not a copy? Is this possible by saying if (object1 == object2)? I was told early on in Java development that I should avoid doing that, but I never found out when it should be used.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Javadoc says: "The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true)."

Comment: Could you show us the code that populates the HashMap? Maybe you make different keys point at the same value?

Comment: I took a look at the code that was populating it. Turns out I was feeding the hash map incorrect keys as was pointed out. Thanks for all the help you've given me and showing me the inner workings of HashMap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I strongly suspect you've misdiagnosed the issue. If you aren't overriding `equals` anywhere (and you're not subclassing anything else that overrides `equals`) then you should indeed have "identity" behaviour.

I would be shocked to hear that this was not the case, to be honest.

If you can product a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem, that would make it easier to look into - but for the moment, I'd *definitely* double-check your suspicions about seeing different objects being treated as equal keys.

Answer (score 3):

The default implementation of `equals()` is done in java.lang.Object:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
return (this == obj);
}
```

Other method `hashCode();` by default returns some kind of reference to the object. I.e. both are unique by default. Equals returns true only for the same object, hashCode() is different for every object.

This is exactly what can create some kind of multiple entries. You can create 2 instances of your class. From your point of view they are equal because they contain identical data. But they are different. So, if you are using these objects as keys of map you are producing 2 entries. If you want to avoid this implement equals and hashCode for your class.

This implementation sometimes is very verbose. HashCodeBuilder and EqualsBuilder from Jakarta project may help you. Here is an example:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, other);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your .equals() and your .hashCode() methods are implemented for all objects that you want to store in the HashMap.  To not have that invites all sorts of problems.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of the objects that you use as the keys in the `HashMap`.

Note that `HashMap` not only uses `equals()`, it also uses `hashCode()`. Your `hashCode()` method must be implemented correctly to match the implementation of the `equals()` method. If the implementation of these methods don't match, you can get unpredictable problems.

See the description of `equals()` and `hashCode()` in the API documentation of class `Object` for the detailed requirements.

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong. There is no requirement to implement `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Comment: Strictly it is not *required* but if you don't implement those methods it will use the default implementations in class `Object` and those often do not do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

FYI you can have IDE's such as Eclipse generate the hashCode & equals methods for you. They'll probably do a better job than if you try to hand-code them yourself.